# What's use of override runtimeType in Dart

Tags: dart

I see I can override `runtimeType` which is defined in `Object` class.

```
class Animal {

  @override
  Type get runtimeType {
  }
}
```

So I want to know what's use of override runtimeType in Dart? And how can I return a Type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's considered a bad idea to override `runtimeType` and `runtimeType` is supposed to be used for debugging purposes only anyway and might even be disallowed in later Dart versions.

As far as I know there are a few places in the core libs where this is used, like `Map` and `List` that in some cases return a different value in `runtimeType` than their actual type. (depending on how you create a `Map` or `List` different implementations are used)